# RegSetValueExA() Function Putting Square In Registry Key Name in C

Tags: c, windows, registry

I am trying to use RegSetValueExA() to put a new entry in the registry. I am taking a variable and passing it to my function that adds the entry. It puts the key in the registry with a square at the end of the name. Such as `Serv Name []`. When I set the name to a defined char array(char name = "Key Name Test") it did not do it. So I am unsure what the issue is.

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    char filePath[150];
    char fileName[30];
    char serviceName[50];
    int portNum;
    char ip[16];

    ..... Ask for information .....

    printf("\nEnter RunKey Service Name:\n");
    fgets(serviceName,49,stdin);

    SetRegistry(serviceName, portNum, filePath, fileName, ip);
}

void SetRegistry(char *kname, int port, char *dir, char *file, char *ip) {
    char argument[150];
    char kLocation[100] = "Software\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Run";
    sprintf(argument, "\"%s\\%s\" -s %s:%i", dir, file, ip, port);
    HKEY hKey;
    RegOpenKeyEx(HKEY_CURRENT_USER, TEXT(kLocation),0,KEY_SET_VALUE,&hKey);
    RegSetValueExA(hKey,kname,0,REG_SZ,(LPBYTE)argument,sizeof(argument)+1);
    RegCloseKey(hKey);
    printf("\nPlaced %s in %s", argument, kLocation);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

`sizeof(arugment)+1` will always be 151… you were probably going for `strlen(argument)+1`, which will depend on the length of the string.

That said, a better way to do it would be to simply save the return value of the `sprintf()` call and use that instead of using `strlen()` to traverse the string again to calculate the length. Also, you should be using `snprintf` not `sprintf` to avoid buffer overflows. `sprintf` should almost never be used.

Comment: Actually my code was wrong. The issue is the with `kname`. Which is the name of the reg key entry. The data goes in just fine, but I will fix that issue.

Comment: Semantically a [`REG_SZ`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms724884) is a null-terminated string. This isn't enforced by `RegSetValueEx` and `RegQueryValueEx`, so programs that get `REG_SZ` values need to be careful to add the null terminator if it's missing, and they should also be courteous to include it when setting the value.

Comment: The OP does not need two null bytes when setting a `REG_SZ`. That's only for `REG_MULTI_SZ`.

Comment: After doing some further testing.. I am printing the contents of the kname that is passed to the function. It is including `\n`. Not the actual character but if I printf("%s...", kname) it will show the kname and then on next line the (...). So it is capturing the enter button as well.

Comment: You can easily strip any trailing newlines by setting the character to null (`while ((kname_len > 1) && kname[kname_len - 1] == '\n') kname[--kname_len] = '\0';`)

Comment: The registry uses the NT object namespace, which only reserves the backslash path separator (forward slash is just another name character), and even backslash isn't reserved in value names. Since NT uses counted `UNICODE_STRING` values, you can even get away with NUL characters in a registry key/value name when using the NT API directly. Only the filesystem namespace rejects names with forward slash, control characters, pipe and the 5 reserved wildcard characters (*?"<>) -- and even that's assuming the filesystem is using standard routines in the FsRTL like Microsoft's NTFS, FAT32, etc.